# FOSS Command-line data viewer?

Tags: software-recommendations, command-line, viewer

Is there a simple, free and open source command-line-accessible (other otherwise programmatically-available) viewer that can be called to visualize a GIS dataset?

I know one could do fancy things like view a raster with matplotlib after converting to numpy with Python, or also simply open a full-on GIS with a file loaded by giving it as a command-line argument, but I'm looking for something very lightweight that gives a simple visualization.

Comment: Sounds like you are discounting python...but I find goepandas with matplotlib simple and lightweight for vectors. Sure there is some complexity to get a full setup going, but once you get going, its easy to view data quickly.  I would have provided an example, but I get the sense it would be something you already know about.

Comment: For software recommendations I think the best place to ask is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, found something that fits: OpenEV https://sourceforge.net/projects/openev/. I can put this up as an answer, if that's not too vain of me to answer my own question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [OpenEV](http://openev.sourceforge.net/), I would also suggest [tuiview](http://tuiview.org/), which is a lightweight PyQt based GIS viewer. It is easily installed via conda.

In my opinion, it is very stable, fast and supports both raster and vector data. It also has some very useful features, such as contrast stretching and a profile tool (see screenshot below).

[image]